Tips to optimize my code (computing joint spectrum of operators taking too long)
I am trying to compute the joint spectrum of two operators, which depend on a value of $n$. The bigger the $n$ the higher the dimension of the space where the operators is defined and hence more eigenvalues to consider. Usually Mathematica runs this fast, say like 5 seconds, but for this example it is taking a lot longer, minutes when I consider $n\geq20$ which are the cases I would like to plot...  Therefore I am wondering if there is something I can do to optimize my code? Any insight is appreciated.
Here is the first function which computes the matrix representative of the operator in the eigenspace of the other operator
 MatrixRepresentativeHH[x_, n_] := Module[{l0, u, hbar, op},
  l0 = x/(2/(n + 1)) + n/2 - 1/2;
   u = Min[l0, n];
  hbar = 2/(n + 1);
  op = Table[0, u + 1, u + 1];
  Do[
   If[m >= 1, 
    op[[m + 1, 
       m]] = (hbar/2)^(3/2) Sqrt[(l0 + 1 - m)*m*(u - m + 1)]];
   If[m <= u - 1, 
    op[[m + 1, 
       m + 2]] = (hbar/2)^(3/
         2) Sqrt[(l0 + 1 - (m + 1))*(m + 1)*(n - (m + 1) + 1)]];
   , {m, 0, u}];
  op
  ]

And then for the joint spectrum we need the spectrum at the a specific eigenspace
Spectrum[x_, n_] := 
 Table[{x, Eigenvalues[MatrixRepresentativeHH[x, n]][[i]]}, {i, 
   1, dimElambda[x, n]}]

and now the joint spectrum
JointSpectrum[n_] := 
 ListPlot[
  Table[Spectrum[i, n], {i, (2/(n + 1))*(1 - n)/2, 3, 2/(n + 1)}], 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]

Any ideas on how I can make it run faster?

you have no definition for dimElambda.  Btw, you should not use UpperCase starting letter for your functions. These are meant to be used by Mathematica only. someone looking at your code will now think these are Mathematica builtin functions.

Table[{x, Eigenvalues[MatrixRepresentativeHH[x, n]][[i]]}, {i, 1, dimElambda[x, n]}] -- this recomputes MatrixRepresentativeHH[x, n] and its Eigenvalues several times (dimElambda[x, n] times to be precise). That is probably one of the reasons for the bad performance.
